# Adding Three20 in our project?

Tags: iphone, three20

How to find /Three20/src folder in downloaded source code ? or i have to create my own folder of that name ?

and Clone the Three20 git repository:
git clone git://github.com/facebook/three20.git is have to run on terminal or what ? Concept not clear ?

any any body help me regarding all the steps clearly ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you don't know how to use git, watch this: [Intro Video to Git](http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html)

You'll need to install git [which you can get here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/)

Lastly, yes, you will need to run `git clone git://github.com/facebook/three20.git`